# autofilling location search box

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I'm learning web design using django as a starting point.  I would like a search box with a drop down auto completing location e.g as [here](http://s2.postimage.org/56n94gip7/Screen_Shot_2011_09_08_at_20_38_18.png).

Can I use a Google API for this?

Comment: Not seeing the example.... :P

Comment: does this link work?  http://postimage.org/image/1n1benfs4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the main plugin you want:

[jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

See the source code section for how to implement.

This google code addon to the above also looks helpful:

[django-ajax-selects](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/)

It uses django 1.0 or greater and jquery 1.26  or greater.